# Why can't the purity of a single qubit be less than $1/2$?

Tags: density-matrix

The density matrix of a single qubit system can be defined as,
$$ \rho= \frac{1}{2}(\hat I+ \vec r.\hat{\vec \sigma})  $$
From here we can derive, $$ Tr(\rho^2)= \frac{1}{2}(1+r^2) $$
Since $ 0\leq r^2\leq1$, we have $$ \frac{1}{2}\leq Tr(\rho^2)\leq 1$$
But I would like to know why purity cannot be less than $50\%$?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. You are essentially showing yourself why the purity is not smaller than $1/2$

Comment: I actually wanted to know the physical significance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just an amount that we think is reasonable to describe the concept of *purity*. If you can find another quantity that is more reasonable than this one, then we can use that quantity as the definition of purity,e.g. you can use $2(Tr(\rho^2)-\frac{1}{2})$ as your definition of purity, but so what? From my point, if you want to quantify some abstract thing, let's say $x$, not all the numbers($f(x)$) are important.

Comment: So it's just a matter of definition?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. To be more concrete, you can consider the quantification of entanglement and coherence, which can easily be found in the review paper of them. There are a lot of functions to quantify them as long as those functions satisfy some axioms, from which you can see that not all numbers are important, and it's just a matter of definition.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I studied a bit and found that there is a lower bound for purity. If $\rho$ is a $n\times n$ matrix ($n$ is the dimension of Hilbert Space as well), then $$\frac{1}{n} \leq Tr(\rho^2) \leq 1$$.